# PHP get start and end date of a week from selected months

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get start and end date of a week from Month but I have no idea how can I do that please help me thanks

**return request**

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "Jan"
  1 => "Feb"
  2 => "Mar"
]
```

**controller**

```
       if ($request->options == "Week") {

            $months = array('Dec','Jan','Feb');

            $dto = new DateTime();
            $dto->setISODate("2021", date('W',strtotime('2021-12-01')));
            $ret['week_start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
            $dto->modify('+6 days');
            $ret['week_end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
            return $ret;

        }
```

Comment: Which day of week is the start of a week? Monday or Sunday? Also, which week are we talking about? The first week in the month? The last week of the month? Do you have to accept the week number?

Comment: Sir I want to get dates like that [week_start] => 2021-12-01 [week_end] => 2021-12-08  

      [week_start] => 2021-12-15 [week_end] => 2021-12-22

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for date/time management in PHP via composer:

```sh
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

```php
echo Carbon::create(2014, 5, 30, 0, 0, 0)->firstOfMonth();                       // 2014-05-01 00:00:00
echo Carbon::create(2014, 5, 30, 0, 0, 0)->firstOfMonth(Carbon::MONDAY);         // 2014-05-05 00:00:00
echo Carbon::create(2014, 5, 30, 0, 0, 0)->lastOfMonth();                        // 2014-05-31 00:00:00
echo Carbon::create(2014, 5, 30, 0, 0, 0)->lastOfMonth(Carbon::TUESDAY);         // 2014-05-27 00:00:00
echo Carbon::create(2014, 5, 30, 0, 0, 0)->nthOfMonth(2, Carbon::SATURDAY);      // 2014-05-10 00:00:00
```